# What is meaning of expression my $var = -s $abc in perl;

Tags: perl

I was trying to understand the meaning of the switch -s in perl.
What does -s signify. I tried to google, did not find any answers.

```
my $a = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
my $b = -s $a;
```

what value will b have? (In terms of a)

Comment: https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html

Comment: Don't use lexical `$a` and `$b`, they're special variables used in [sort](http://p3rl.org/sort).

Answer (score 10):

It depends on the content of the file named `1048576`.

See [the documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html):

> ```
> -s  File has nonzero size (returns size in bytes).
> ```